# Pagination not working with component inside Vuetify table cell with slot

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to render markdown in my vuetify table. I was able to get it working using v-slot for that particular column but now when I use pagination the column that uses v-slot does not update while the rest do. What am I missing?

```
  <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :search="search"
      :class="className"
      :item-key="itemKey"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
  >
      <template v-slot:item.description="{ item }">
          <vue-markdown>{{ item.description }}</vue-markdown>
      </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

This is the markdown library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-markdown-v2

edit: Just tested the v-slot without the markdown component and it works as expected.

Comment: it is said in package description that the default slot renders only once, at creation. one workaround will be to use a key on `vue-markdown` that changes with the `item`. for ex: `:key="item.id"`.

Comment: `:key="item"` worked, thanks.